# How to replace #VALUE! with blanks

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am following [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Hide-error-values-and-error-indicators-in-cells-d171b96e-8fb4-4863-a1ba-b64557474439) to try and replace #VALUE! errors with blanks however when I follow that and try and create a new rule nothing happens.

[image]

IS there a way to replace #VALUE with blanks rather than change each individual formula to incorporate this change?

In my example K, N, and P have #VALUE errors.
K

```
My K cell value looks like: =IF(ISERR(SEARCH("Q "," " & 'Quick Analysis'!$D6 & " ")),'Quick Analysis'!T6,'Quick Analysis'!S6)
```

N

```
=IF(ISERR(SEARCH("SR "," " & 'Quick Analysis'!$D6& " ")),'Quick Analysis'!AC6,AF6)
```

P

```
=K6*(L6-33)
```

There is also a hidden cell Q:

which contains:

```
=SUM(P6:P11)
```

Changing these through formulas get complicated.  IS there a way to do this through conditional formatting?
Thanks.

Comment: Have a look at **`IsError`**. Should give you what you need

Comment: @Zac I've included my exact formula's.  It gets complicated trying to make them blanks as far as I can tell it's not working for me.   I can show exact examples used in an edit

Comment: You can use Conditional Formatting to "hide" the error, by turning the text the same color as the background, but the best method is to deal with the errors using the IFERROR method in the link: `IFERROR(...,"")` where `...` is your formula.

Comment: Just an FYI, the conditional formatting option will leave the little green triangle in the upper left corner of all the cells with errors.  To get rid of those you will need to adjust the settings in options not to flag the errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column K, N and P. Go to Conditional Formatting, and use formula

```
=ISERROR(K1)
```

Set font color to white in format and click OK. See if this works.